# How to know which QPushButton in a QTableWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm sorry, I know the question has already been asked before, however, I really can't have a solution for me.

My situation is very basic : I have a tableview and in each row I have some QPushButtons. The difficulty for me is to know which button has been clicked.

I've read about Mappers, ... but it doesn't work. Eclipse is not happy, exeception, ...

```
signalMapper = QSignalMapper()            
for row,dossier in enumerate(Dossier.listeDossiers):
  button = QPushButton("Archive")
  signalMapper.setMapping(button, row)
  QObject.connect(button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), signalMapper, SLOT("map()"))
  self.dlg.ui.tableWidget_dossiers.setCellWidget(row, 5, button)

def getArchive(self,row):
   print "Row " + str(row)
```

I know this is wrong or some lines are missing, but I tried a lot of solutions.
Thanks
Regards
Etienne

Comment: do you wanna get to know in slot which button is clicked?

Comment: What's the error? Your code looks correct except that you probably want to connect to one of the signal mapper's `mapped()` signals to receive clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [QButtonGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html):

```
    self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
    self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.getArchive)
    for row, dossier in enumerate(Dossier.listeDossiers):
        button = QPushButton("Archive")
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, row)
        self.dlg.ui.tableWidget_dossiers.setCellWidget(row, 5, button)

def getArchive(self, row):
    print "Row " + str(row)
```